# MDX: Calculate percentage from a measure present in the same dimension

Tags: mdx, pentaho, google-analytics-api, saiku

I am learning MDX and I have a question to create a percentage.
Basically, I extract data from Google Analytics API for multiple sets of pages.
For each set, I extract the number of UniquePageviews.

The SQL columns looks like that:

- date
- deviceCategory
- medium
- uniquePageviews
- transactions
- set_of_page (the rows contain the name of the set of pages. To simplify: 1. First, 2. Second, 3. Third )
- Brand (Brand A, Brand B)
- Market (Market X, Market Y)

Here is the current view I have:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTC30.png

What I want to have is the percentage of UniquePageviews from the set of page 1 to 2 and from 2 to 3 So: UniquePageviews 2/Uniquepageviews 1 &  UniquePageviews 3/Uniquepageviews 2.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xf2gc.png

Do you know a simple way to do that in MDX?

Here is the code I have for now to display the pageviews:

```
WITH
SET [~COLUMNS_Brand_Brand] AS
SET [~COLUMNS_Market_Market] AS
    {[Market].[Market].Members}
SET [~COLUMNS_set_of_page segment_set_of_page] AS
    {[set_of_page].[set_of_page].Members}
SET [~ROWS] AS
    {[Date].[Date].Members}
SELECT
NON EMPTY NonEmptyCrossJoin([~COLUMNS_Brand_Brand], NonEmptyCrossJoin([~COLUMNS_Market_Market], [~COLUMNS_set_of_page_set_of_page])) ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY [~ROWS] ON ROWS
FROM [MySQL_Cube]
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

At the moment your `mdx` is picking up the measure implicitly? All mdx queries need something to measure so your current script must be picking up the default cube measure - I'll call this `[Measures].[NumTransactions]`.
Also your first SET seems to be blank. Therefore lets assume the full, *explicit* script is:

```
WITH
SET [~COLUMNS_Brand_Brand] AS {[Brand].[Brand].[All]}
SET [~COLUMNS_Market_Market] AS
    {[Market].[Market].Members}
SET [~COLUMNS_set_of_page segment_set_of_page] AS
    {[set_of_page].[set_of_page].Members}
SET [~ROWS] AS
    {[Date].[Date].Members}
SELECT
NON EMPTY NonEmptyCrossJoin([~COLUMNS_Brand_Brand], NonEmptyCrossJoin([~COLUMNS_Market_Market], [~COLUMNS_set_of_page_set_of_page])) ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY [~ROWS] ON ROWS
FROM [MySQL_Cube]
WHERE [Measures].[NumTransactions];
```

I use MS SSAS so a little unsure of nitation that works with you but just to help me I'll switch to the `*` operator for cross-joins:

```
WITH
SET [~COLUMNS_Brand_Brand] AS {[Brand].[Brand].[All]}
SET [~COLUMNS_Market_Market] AS
    {[Market].[Market].Members}
SET [~COLUMNS_set_of_page segment_set_of_page] AS
    {[set_of_page].[set_of_page].Members}
SET [~ROWS] AS
    {[Date].[Date].Members}
SELECT
NON EMPTY 
   [~COLUMNS_Brand_Brand]
  *[~COLUMNS_Market_Market]
  *[~COLUMNS_set_of_page_set_of_page] ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY [~ROWS] ON ROWS
FROM [MySQL_Cube]
WHERE [Measures].[NumTransactions];
```

I'm hoping (as untested and I'm a little unsure all context will be retained) that we can just add a custom meassure that divides the current page by the previous one to get the percentage:

```
WITH
SET [~COLUMNS_Brand_Brand] AS {[Brand].[Brand].[All]}
SET [~COLUMNS_Market_Market] AS
    {[Market].[Market].Members}
SET [~COLUMNS_set_of_page segment_set_of_page] AS
    {[set_of_page].[set_of_page].Members}
SET [~ROWS] AS
    {[Date].[Date].Members}
MEMBER [Measures].[NumTransactionsPercent] AS
     [set_of_page].CURRENTMEMBER
   / [set_of_page].CURRENTMEMBER.LAG(1)
SELECT
NON EMPTY 
   [~COLUMNS_Brand_Brand]
  *[~COLUMNS_Market_Market]
  *[~COLUMNS_set_of_page_set_of_page] ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY [~ROWS] ON ROWS
FROM [MySQL_Cube]
WHERE [Measures].[NumTransactionsPercent];  //[Measures].[NumTransactions];
```